# Add Active Class to Current selected svg using js

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, snap.svg

the svg id = "map" 
the normal path class = "T" 
Selected class ="Tactive" 
Tcurrent is a active shave by Default

```
var oMap= document.getElementById("map");
var oRng= document.getElementsByClassName("T");
var Tcurrent


for (var j = 0; j < oRng.length; j++) {

  oRng[j].addEventListener("click", function () {
  Tcurrent = document.getElementsByClassName("T Tactive");
  Tcurrent[0].classList ="T" 
  this.classList = "T Tactive";

  });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this may help...

```js
$('.svg').click(function() {
  $('.svg').removeClass('selected'); // removes initial selected classes.
  
  this.classList.add('selected'); // adds selected class for clicked svg.
});
```

```css
.svg {
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 8px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #eee;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.svg:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.selected {
  border: 2px solid #333;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Selected</title>
</head>
<body>
  <main>
     <div class="svg">a.</div>
     <div class="svg">b.</div>
  </main>
  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```